# It would have been nice to know that shared links include my user id

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, security, sharing, short-links

I noticed that every short-link/permalink that I share while I'm logged in includes my user id.

It would have been really nice if the UI had highlighted this fact in the link sharing popup so that people who don't always intend to share their identity elsewhere can remain secure knowing that they haven't.

Comment: You're right that this isn't obvious. However, it's done to be able to award badges for sharing posts and getting so many people to click on your link.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thanks. I read about why it's done [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/), but I don't think that conflicts with what I'm asking for. Letting me know that I'm about to share my User ID would not interfere with that.

Comment: I agree that it should be more obvious. I didn't know if you were aware of the badges and the reasoning behind putting the ID in the URL.

Comment: Contrary to the [tag:status-declined] there I *do* think this warrants consideration. The UI should make sure you're aware of the presence of this information, especially given there's zero harm in doing so